spring config server not load property file when the file is specified in spring.config.import
I got problem in spring cloud config server. I use native file config, the config file is classpath:/config-base.yml, that's fine.
But my config server also need read this config file, so I add spring.config.import=classpath:/config-base.yml, after this, the config server will not load this property file.
Why was that, nor any way the config server can also be a config client to read that config file?
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  config:
    import: classpath:/config-base.yml
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/


Well, I find another way instead of use spring.config.import, use spring.config.name can let server read this file in addition
spring.config.name=config-base

